# How to secure URLs in Django

Tags: python, django, security, url

Is there a way to prevent users from accessing some (or all) URLs in application? For example, I am following Django tutorial and one of the examples has a URL:

```
#music/album/<pk>/delete
url(r'image/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.ImageDelete.as_view(), name='image-delete'),
```

that deletes database entry give `pk` as a parameter. Of course, now it is possible to delete this entry with just copy-pasting the URL with any existing primary-key, so what is the best practice to avoid it? Thanks

**EDIT.** Based on the replies and comments, I decided to elaborate a bit more. I am actually using `DeleteView` and forms with `POST` request as @solarissmoke suggested in answer.

```
<form action="{% url 'album:image-delete' image.id%}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="{{ image.id }}"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
</form>
```

and in my `views.py`:

```
class ImageDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    # if you successfully delete the object, page redirects to <homepage>
    success_url = reverse_lazy('album:index')
```

So, there were few suggestions on checkin whether the user is verified to delete URL entry (e.x. the image) and to add pop up/notification to verify if the user *indeed* wants to delete the entry. However, it does not feel like a complete solution. In the comments I brought example of Facebook, where you can *not* delete imeage/post by just copy-pasting the *delete* URL. Surely I'm not asking for Facebook-like security, however, I'm really curious how can secure URLs so that it's nearly impossible for regular user to delete entry with simple copy-pasting. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a rather broad topic, there are many ways to do it. I recommend starting from here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is that you should not be allowing modification of data like this through HTTP `GET` requests, which are intended (as the name suggests) for getting data rather than updating it.

You should use forms and `POST` requests to perform actions like deleting objects etc. Django provides [lots of helper views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#generic-editing-views) for doing this. For example `DeleteView`:

> A view that displays a confirmation page and deletes an existing object. The given object will only be deleted if the request method is `POST`. If this view is fetched via `GET`, it will display a confirmation page that should contain a form that `POST`s to the same URL.

The advantages of using these views are:

- You can make sure the user has permissions to edit an object before making any changes. Django will perform the basic checks (e.g., CSRF) for you. You can augment the views to perform additional checks like [making sure a user is logged in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users) or [checking any other permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin).
- You can enforce [Cross-Site Request Forgery Protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/).
- It is not possible to accidentally delete an object by visiting a URL a second time (as the documentation above explains).

Comment: it is worth mentioning use of decorators and/or new security mixins that can be used with generic views

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways.. e.g:

```
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated() and user.profile.can_delete_image(image_pk):
    # only then, image can be deleted by this user
    # can_delete_image(image_pk) is defined by you
else: 
    raise DeletePermissionDenied # you can define your own Exception, just for fun
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Follow up question would be: let's assume user has permissions, but then he/she accidentally mistypes `pk` and deletes something that was not supposed to be deleted?

Comment: @Emily do you mean that in the case when the image didn't belong to her?

Comment: @RA123 not necessarily, let's say we have a web app with a database and 5 users which manage this application (not the actual source code though). With these type of links one of five users can easily delete the whole row without anyone even noticing it, right?

Comment: Exactly, this is what the code is supposed to do. The only thing you can do  to make sure that it is not a 'mistake' is to ask again if the user is sure to remove the image (on the current link), by using a form (as you like). And further on form submission (you can add on a captcha thing), delete the image. This should be secure enough for such mistakes?

Comment: @RA123 Okay, maybe I'm not being very clear. Best example I can come up with is Facebook. You can't delete your own photo by just pasting a URL, so that's the kind of security I'm looking for

Comment: @Emily Then, simplest thing would be to use a uuid instead of primary key in your url. A user deleting an image by 'mistake' by typing the correct url (that collides with some image uuid as in db), I can assure if this happens it wasn't a mistake (and by assure, I mean it is highly improbable that this happens by mistake).